# Convert a style in to a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I need top get this element and push it in an array as a string

```
<div style="height:48px;width:48px;background-image:url(https://static.u.gg/assets/lol/riot_static/10.10.3216176/img/sprite/champion0.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:-48px -48px;zoom:0.625;-moz-transform:scale(0.625);-moz-transform-origin:0 0"></div>
```

I wrote this code, but it converts the style string in an objcet

```
    let data = await page.evaluate(() =>{
    //let champ = document.querySelector('div[class="pro-match-card win"] > div[class="outcome"] > strong > div').innerText;
    let champ = [];
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[class="champion opp"] > div > div');
    for (var element of elements){
    champ.push(element.style);
    }
    return {
        champ,
    }
})
```

the code returns this:

```
{
  '0': 'height',
  '1': 'width',
  '2': 'background-image',
  '3': 'background-repeat-x',
  '4': 'background-repeat-y',
  '5': 'background-position-x',
  '6': 'background-position-y',
  '7': 'zoom'
},
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: _"I need top get this element and push it in an array as a string"_ - Then why are you using `.style` instead of `.outerHTML`?

Comment: Can you share the desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
for (var element of elements){
    champ.push(element.style.cssText);
}
```

Instead of:

```
for (var element of elements){
    champ.push(element.style);
}
```

This is because element.style property returns an array of individual style property while element.style.cssText returns everything as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
return {
        champ,
}
```

To

```
return champ;
```

And it will work.

In ES6 and above `return { champ }` is executed as `return {champ: champ}` .

Comment: _"...is executed as return {champ: champ}"_ - Which should be another hint that the output is not possible with script in OPs question.